# How can l start postgresql database using linux crontab?

Tags: linux, postgresql, cron

```
su - postgres
pg_ctl start
```

postgresql database is starting in this way.

but when I use linux crontab to start postgresql,it has failed.

```
su - postgres
crontab -e

*/1 * * * * nohup /home/postgres/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start &
```

postgresql is not starting.

I want to know why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define which PostgreSQL instance to start.

Try to add `-D "PGDATA"`.

For example:

```
nohup /home/postgres/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -D /pg/data &
```

If your Linux distribution is using systemd and a systemd unit has been defined for PostgreSQL you can also use `systemctl` to start PostgreSQL